# Composite indexes on fact tables in a data warehouse - datamart

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

Is it a best practice to keep composite unique indexes on fact tables in a Oracle EDW - data mart for avoiding duplicates? will it impact ETL data load performance? Please provide your thoughts on this topic. What are other alternative ways to gain SLA for ETL load?

Answer (score 1):

Each insert into a table that has an index will cause that index to be updated causing IO and slowing it down a bit. So loading into a table with indexes whether unique or not will be a bit slower. You can drop that index, load and then create it again. It will reduce index fragmentation and usually will be faster with large loads.

I'm surprised to see a unique index on a fact table. Usually there is not so much uniqueness required there and in general data warehouses denormalize and duplicate data.

It all depends on your case. If you can use ETL to avoid undesired duplicates do it instead of using an index. Don't create this index if the sole purpose is data integrity/consistency. Indexes get huge so they better be useful for your queries.